# Insert legend into plot that is associated with factors

Tags: r, legend

I have a `plot(x,y)` associated with two other factors `z` and `t`. There are three `levels` in `z` and two levels in `t`. How do I properly use `legend` function to insert `legend` to give three levels of z with t1, such as z1t1, z2t1, z3t1, and three levels of z with t2, such as z1t2, z2t2, z3t2? In other words, the legends should show a total of six.

```
with(df, plot(x, y, 
                 pch = as.numeric(as.factor(paste(z,t))), 
                 col = as.numeric(as.factor(paste(z, t)))))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like what you are looking for.

UPDATE: Factors in the legend are sorted now.

```
#creating test data 

x <- rnorm(20)
y <- x + runif(20)
dat <-  data.frame("x" = x, "y" = y, 
                   z = sample(c("z1", "z2", "z3"), 20, replace = TRUE),
                   t = sample(c("t1", "t2"), 20, replace = TRUE))

#it's quicker to do the pasting outside
dat$zt <- as.numeric(as.factor(paste(dat$z,dat$t)))


with(dat, plot(x, y, 
               pch = zt, 
               col = zt))
with(dat, legend(x = "bottomright",
                 legend = sort(unique(paste(z,t))),
                 pch = unique(zt),
                 col = unique(zt)))
```

Hope it helps.

[image]

Comment: OMG, you're a LEGEND! :P 
btw, if i wish to arrange all z1 together then z2 follow by z3, how can it be done?
Thanks very much for your help!

Comment: No big deal. :-) You can just do `legend = sort(unique(paste(z,t)))`.

Comment: I tried the code but it seemed that the symbols remain in the same order but the zt are sorted. Did i miss something? like binding pch to zt?

Comment: I made an update so you see the whole code which gave me the plot you see in the answer. Found a difference?